# How to run "docker-compose up" command in .sh file?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, cron

I am trying to run Docker container every day using a cron job.

```
* * * * * /Desktop/cron1.sh
```

This is my cron1.sh file:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir /home/tomato/bizzz    #working
cd bizzz             #not working
docker-compose up      #not working
```

Comment: Does your script fail even when you run it outside of `cron` ?

Comment: @Aserre script run perfect outside of cron

Comment: Try adding `-d` to the `docker-compose` command? I'm not sure you can start (without detaching) from cron, where there is no terminal to attach to. Does the cron email you any error output?

Comment: Is docker-compose on the path when cron runs?

Comment: If you can't `cd bizzz`, but you can `mkdir /home/tomato/bizzz`, then obviously your current working directory isn't `/home/tomato`. One of the key things to remember, when working with cron, is not to assume anything about your environment -- not your PATH, not your working directory, etc.

Comment: Anyhow -- `exec 2>/tmp/log; set -x` in your script, and you'll have logs in `/tmp/log` that should shed light on what's going on.

Comment: (BTW, in the future, don't just describe something as "working" or "not working", but how you *know* if something is working or not working. For example: How did you determine that the `cd` didn't function? If you got an error, that's likely to be a useful clue, and it should be included in your question)

Comment: Thanks a lot all guys

Comment: hey guys you know why its not working on EC2 conatainer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a couple potential problems with this:

- Is the home directory for the user (/home/tomato) that is running the cron job? If not, then you'll need to `cd /home/tomato/bizzz`.
- You are also creating the directory `bizzz` then running `docker-compose up` with nothing in it...?
- Also `docker-compose` may not be in the `PATH` for cron. For example, one way to ensure that it is add `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` to the beginning of your cron job.

Comment: thanks it's work for me. add two line in my 'cronetab -e' 1.SHELL=/bin/sh
2.PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Comment: hey @nateleavitt you know why its not working on EC2 conatainer ?